# How to Import nodes modules in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, import

hope you're doing well.

I'm new at react native and i'm stuck with a problem while trying to import a node module.

I need to create an app that will get orders from the API of a Wordpress Website with WooCommerce.

I first created a project with the command `create-react-native-app picking` then `npm install`. It's creating a structure like this in the project folder named `picking`:

```
node_modules
App.js
app.json
App.test.js
etc....
```

Then I installed the package `woocommerce-api` with `npm install woocommerce-api --save` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api). This package allow me to do request to the WooCommerce API easier.

I want to not put the config to the WooCommerce API in the `App.js`, so I created a folder src and a folder woocommerce with a file api.js (should I write it with the first letter in uppercase ?) in it and I added `import Api from 'picking/src/woocommerce/api';` in my App.js.

So now the structure is

```
node_modules
src
  -- woocommerce
    -- api.js
App.js
app.json
App.test.js
etc....
```

The problem is that I can't achieve to import the `WooCommerceAPI` module from `woocommerce-api`, no matter what I set in path to get the module.

There is the file `api.js` at the moment :

```
import WooCommerceAPI from '../../woocommerce-api';

var Api = new WooCommerceAPI({
    url: 'http://localhost/mysite',
    consumerKey: 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    wp_api: true,
    version: '/wc/v2',
    queryStringAuth: true
});

export default Api;
```

And I get the error :

```
Unable to resolve module '../../woocommerce-api' from etc ...
```

I can't find what is the problem and why this is not working. If you could help me on this, it would be very nice.

Have a nice day everyone :)

**EDIT**: I changed the line for the import to `import WooCommerceAPI from 'woocommerce-api';` and I got a new error : `Metro Bundler has  encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details`, but there is nothing in the terminal except `Failed building JavaScript bundle`.

**EDIT2**: I downgrade node from 9.4 to 8.0.0 and restart the project. I got the same error but in the terminal i now get this in yellow/orange : `Problem checking node_modules dependencies: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: When you import a dependency, you generally use a non-relative import that is resolved by your toolchain. i.e. `import WooCommerceAPI from "woocommerce-api";`

Comment: I tried it but then I get another error In Expo: `Metro Bundler has encoutered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details`. But there is nothing in my terminal ...

Comment: Well, thats the correct way. That new error is clearly not what you've asked about

Comment: I didn't thought this was the correct way because this was creating an huge error that i can't understand,  while the error that i ask about said at least that it can't find the module ...

Comment: That is contrary to your stated goal of importing the dependency. How can someone answer such a question.

Comment: You partially already answered. Stop making me look stupid, i'm in the fog about react native and how imports or anything works, I asked the question with a lot of details and with what is going wrong. You answered me and put me on my way, but this is not resolved. I'm gonna edit my question to add the new error that is related to the import too.

Comment: I'm not trying to make you look stupid. However, I have no idea how to answer your followup question. It should be asked separately.

Comment: It shouldn't be because this is the same problem but with a new error. If I comment my line that import  my api.js file I have no problems. The problem is when i add the import. And if you don't see any error in my api.js file that can make the bundle broken that means that this is the import that don't work.

Comment: But they are different errors. The bundler is failing when the module _is_ included. That is very different.

Comment: Look, i don't know why my import don't work. So the question "How to Import nodes modules in react native" still make sense while i can't achieve to make it work. You see ? I'm not gonna create a new question because, it will have the same Title and the same content, this is meaningless.

Comment: Well, I can't help. I don't know about the new error. Best of luck to you.

Comment: I found what might be a [helpful example](https://github.com/minhcasi/react-native-woocommerce)

Comment: I tried to install it but i can't make it work ... and i compare the WooCommerceAPI.js file to the file that is in the module woocommerce-api and they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I find a workaround. In fact, the import is working. For some reason that i don't know, this is the npm package that is not working and make the app crash.

So I removed the package `woocommerce-api` and I create a file in `src/woocommerce` called `woocommerce-api.js`, then I copied the content of this https://github.com/minhcasi/react-native-woocommerce/blob/master/WooCommerceAPI.js that is the same as the one in the npm package and I pasted it in my `woocommerce-api.js`. I import it in my `api.js`file and "voilà" !

Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you install `woocommerce-api` in your project there is no need to place the location like `../../woocommerce-api`.

just change `../../woocommerce-api` to `woocommerce-api` and your project should work.